# How can I filter duplicates/repeated fields in bigquery?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have a table without primaryKey. And I am trying to get the events of the earliest date grouped by id.

This is what small piece of mytable looks like:

```
|----------|------------------|-------------|
|    id    |       date       |    events   |
|----------|------------------|-------------|
|     1    |2020-04-11 3:44:20|     call    |
|----------|------------------|-------------|
|     3    |2020-04-21 7:59:06| appointment |
|----------|------------------|-------------|
|     1    |2020-04-17 1:14:32| appointment |
|----------|------------------|-------------|
|     2    |2020-04-10 3:41:17|   feedback  |
|----------|------------------|-------------|
|     1    |2020-04-23 1:36:13| appointment |
|----------|------------------|-------------|
|     3    |2020-04-12 4:55:38|     call    |
|----------|------------------|-------------|
```

This is the result I am looking for:

```
|----------|------------------|-------------|
|    id    |       date       |    events   |
|----------|------------------|-------------|
|     1    |2020-04-11 3:44:20|     call    |
|----------|------------------|-------------|
|     2    |2020-04-10 3:41:17|   feedback  |
|----------|------------------|-------------|
|     3    |2020-04-12 4:55:38|     call    |
|----------|------------------|-------------|
```

I am trying to get events by id only for their respective MIN(date) but the problem is that I have to SELECT events but then I have to add events to GROUP BY so I can't GROUP BY id only as I would like to.
I have tried a lot of different version but here is one:

```
SELECT id, MIN(date), events
FROM mydataset.mytable
GROUP BY id, events
```

Please keep in mind that my table is much larger than this.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select array_agg(t order by date asc limit 1)[ordinal(1)].*
from mydataset.mytable t
group by t.id;
```

Or the more traditional method of using `row_number()`:

```
select t.* except (seqnum)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
      from mydataset.mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thx @Gordon, both solution work. FYI, the first one worked with `t.id` at last line. Without the alias I was getting "Column order_id contains an aggregation function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY"

Comment: @Jones . . . Oh, that is interesting -- strange but interesting.  It looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify what you have as an `uncorrelated` subquery

```
select *
from mytable 
where (id, date) in (select id, min(date)
                     from mytable
                     group by id);
```

If your DB supports `window functions` you could also do

```
select distinct id, 
                min(date) over(partition by id) date,
                first_value(events) over (partition by id order by date asc) events
from mytable;
```

**Outputs**

```
+----+---------------------+----------+
| id |        date         |  events  |
+----+---------------------+----------+
|  1 | 2020-04-11 03:44:20 | call     |
|  2 | 2020-04-10 03:41:17 | feedback |
|  3 | 2020-04-12 04:55:38 | call     |
+----+---------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A join to a derived table might perform better, esp. if id and date are indexed:

```
select m.*
 from mytable m
  join (select id, min(date) date
    from mytable
    group by id ) x
   on m.id = x.id
    and m.date = x.date
;
```

Comment: BigQuery doesn't support indexes, so this answer really isn't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> to built on Gordon's answer with Jones' comment -

Below version does not require using alias and allows use of just `id` in `GROUP BY`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY date LIMIT 1)[ORDINAL(1)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY id
```